# Performing classification using composite of Sentinel 2 instead Landsat8 in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am looking fo the equivalent of the following code:

```
    // Load the Landsat 8 scaled radiance image collection.
var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');

// Make a cloud-free composite.
var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: landsatCollection,
  asFloat: true
});
```

I know that the equivalent for this i just loading the landsat-2 collection. But at the end I want to use something like this (this is where it fails for sentinel-2, but works for landsat-8):

```
    // Merge the three geometry layers into a single FeatureCollection.
//classes i uses for the classification
var newfc = urban.merge(vegetation).merge(water);

// Use these bands for classification.
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
// The name of the property on the points storing the class label.
var classProperty = 'landcover';

// Sample the composite to generate training data.  Note that the
// class label is stored in the 'landcover' property.
var training = composite.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: [classProperty],
  scale: 30
});

// Train a CART classifier.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: classProperty,
});

// Print some info about the classifier (specific to CART).
print('CART, explained', classifier.explain());

// Classify the composite.
var classified = composite.classify(classifier);
Map.centerObject(newfc);
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['red', 'green', 'blue']});
```